# Passing a value into a python variable via Splinter

Tags: python

I'm looking at a web page and making a yes/no decision. I'm trying to create a prompt that will allow me to pass the "yes" / "no" to a python variable via Splinter.

1.) Page loads

2.) Execute something like `browser.execute_script("window.prompt()")` with a yes/ no to a variable

3.) Some business logic is done based on that variable

ie -

```
data = browser.execute_script("window.prompt()")
if data == 'yes':
  print('the value is good')
else:
  print('the value is bad')
```

Is there a good way to go about doing this?

Comment: It's not going to work. Why don't you use Python's `input`, or get that value as a command line arg?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if it was possible. I think I can get it to work the way I want using `input`

Comment: Yes, using splinter is exactly the wrong way to go about getting input from a user. It's for *automating* browser interaction, which is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good way to go about doing this?

No. Use Python's `input` (or `raw_input` if using Python 2), or get that value as a command line argument.